# is it okay to run a binary logistic regression with groups of unequal sizes?

Tags: regression

My data looks like this:

Group 1: outcome 1 - 200, outcome 2 - 750 Group 2: outcome 1 - 300, outcome 2 - 900

Group 2's likelihood of having outcome 2 is 75%, while Group 1's likelihood of having outcome 2 is 79%.

If I run a binary logistic regression on this data, Group 2 is significantly less likely to have outcome 2. Based on the group's background, I was expecting the opposite.

Is outcome 2 truly more likely in Group 1, or is this just because Group 1 has a smaller total sample size than Group 2?

Is the binary logistic regression affected by the groups having different sizes?

Comment: 200, 750, 300, 900, is this count data? Do you have the raw data also?

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by the "likelihood" and also what exact model you are estimating (i.e. what are the dependent and independent variables and how are they coded)?

Comment: The arithmetic is wrong.  And if logistic regression could not handle varying denominators it would have never taken off.  The logistic model for the 2-group problem is just a rephrasing of two proportions.

Comment: Building on what @FrankHarrell wrote, the common $\chi^2$ test of the equality of two proportions  can be phrased as a test of a logistic regression model (specifically a score test, one of the “big three” tests from an introductory statistical theory class, the other two being Wald and likelihood ratio).